# CakePHP 3.9.4: Use a method of a Model in a Component

Tags: php, cakephp

Recently I have inherited a web application that is developed using CakePHP 1.2.x ... I was assigned a task to upgrade it to a version that will support PHP 7.4.x because the server, on which the application is hosted, will be ending support for PHP 5.4 starting January 2021 ... I am fairly new to CakePHP but I have chosen to upgrade the application to version 3.9.4 of CakePHP. Application has a `UserAuthComponent` and the `login()` method in this component calls upon another method `authsomeLogin()` located in a `User` Model.

This is how it is done in `UserAuthComponent` the 1.2.x way:

```
public function login($type = 'guest', $credentials = null) {
        $user=array();
        if (is_string($type) && ($type=='guest' || $type=='cookie')) {
            App::import("Model", "User");
            $userModel = new User;
            $user = $userModel->authsomeLogin($type, $credentials);
        } elseif (is_array($type)) {
            $user =$type;
        }
        Configure::write($this->configureKey, $user);
        $this->Session->write('UserAuth', $user);
        return $user;
    }
```

And this how I am trying to do in `UserAuthComponent` the 3.9.4 way:

```
function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->controller = $this->_registry->getController();
    }

public function login($type = 'guest', $credentials = null)
    {
        $user = array();
        if (is_string($type) && ($type == 'guest' || $type == 'cookie')) {
            // App::import("Model", "User");
            $this->controller->loadModel('Users');

            $user = $this->controller->Users->authsomeLogin($type, $credentials);
            debug($user);
        } elseif (is_array($type)) {
            $user = $type;
        }
        Configure::write($this->configureKey, $user);
        $this->Session->write('UserAuth', $user);
        return $user;
    }
```

But doing so I encounter this error and I am not sure how to troubleshoot it.

[image: error I am facing]

I would really appreciate any kind of help or guidance regarding this issue. Looking forward to your answers and suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error message already gives it away, have you tried checking for the possible problems listed there?

Comment: I don't think that `authsomeLogin` was ever part of Cake. Where did that function come from in the 1.2 version?

Comment: @GregSchmidt ... The `authsomeLogin` method is defined in model named `User` ... my issue is that how should i import the model to use it's methods

Comment: @ndm ... yes i have tried `authsomeLogin` method is defined in a model ... I am not getting around on how to call a method defined in a model in to a component.

Comment: What you've done would appear to correctly load the Users model. What does `debug(get_class($this->controller->Users))` give you right after that `loadModel` call?